# Change opacity of an image in an overlay on click over overlay

Tags: javascript, html, css, google-maps-api-3

I have an overlay on google map, the overlay contains two images. I want to change the opacity of the image when the user clicks on the overlay or on the top of image inside the overlay.I have tried to use domlistener but it doesn't seem to work.
Here's the code any help will be great.

```js
function initialize() {
 
  var myLatlng = new google.maps.LatLng(31.6167,65.7167);
  var mapProp = {
 zoom:9,
 center: myLatlng,
   mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.TERRAIN,
    disableDefaultUI: true,
    scrollwheel: false,
    disableDoubleClickZoom: true,
    panControl: false, 
 scaleControl: false,
 touchmove: false

   
  };
  var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map-canvas"),mapProp);
  map.overlayMapTypes.insertAt(0, new CoordMapType(new google.maps.Size(256, 256)));
  var swBound = new google.maps.LatLng(31.35,64.69);
  var neBound = new google.maps.LatLng(31.95,65.39);
  var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds(swBound, neBound);
  var srcImg = 'Capture.png';
  var srcImg_2 = 'Lof1.png';
  overlay = new USGSOverlay(bounds, srcImg,srcImg_2, map);
 

 } 

function USGSOverlay(bounds, image, img, map) {

  this.bounds_ = bounds;
  this.image_ = image;
  this.map_ = map;
  this.img_ = img;
 
  this.div_ = null;
  this.setMap(map);
}
USGSOverlay.prototype.onAdd = function() {

  var div = document.createElement('div');
  div.style.borderStyle = 'none';
  div.style.borderWidth = '0px';
  div.style.position = 'absolute';

  var img = document.createElement('img');
  img.src = this.image_;
  img.style.width = '100%';
  img.style.height = '100%';
  img.style.position = 'absolute';
  img.className= 'lof_class';
  div.appendChild(img);
  var image = document.createElement('img');
  image.src = this.img_;
  image.style.width = '100%';
  image.style.height = '100%';
  image.style.position = 'absolute';
  image.className= 'lof_class';
  div.className= 'carousel';
  div.style.cursor= 'pointer';
  div.setAttribute("data-slide","1");
  div.appendChild(image);
 


  this.div_ = div;
  var panes = this.getPanes();
  panes.overlayLayer.appendChild(div);
   var me = this;
   google.maps.event.addDomListener(div, 'click', function() {
   image.style.opacity= '0.5';
  });

  
};
```

Comment: Could you provide a [Minimal, Complete, Tested and Readable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that demonstrates your issue?

Comment: There you go..., I have added the initialize function but the DomListener is located in onAdd method

Comment: please provide a [Minimal, Complete, Tested and Readable example that demonstrates your issue](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), including any HTML/CSS/images required to test it (**in the question itself**)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found it, you have to use overlayMouseTarget to get the click functionality on the overlay...